# How can I assign ng-repeat item value to ng-model?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

How can I assing the value of an item from items using ng-repeat in ng-model?

in below ng-repeat:

```
<ul ng-repeat="post in allposts" class="timeline">
```

I want to set value of {{post.userEmail}}, like this:

```
<input type="hidden" ng-model="Notify.destEmail[post.userEmail]" />
```

Below is my code:

```
<ul ng-repeat="post in allposts" class="timeline">
                    <li>
                        <div class="timeline-badge"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-check"></i></div>
                        <div class="timeline-panel">
                            <div class="timeline-heading">
                                <h4 class="timeline-title">{{ post.postText}}</h4>
                                </p>
                                <form role="form">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-xs-8 col-md-4">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <input type="text" ng-model='Notify.secEmail'
                                                       placeholder="Email of the person who can help?" class="form-control"
                                                       ></div>
                                        </div>
                                            <div class="col-xs-8 col-md-4">
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <input type="text" ng-model="Notify.message"
                                                           placeholder="Enter a Message or Phone number" class="form-control"
                                                           >
                                                    <input type="hidden" ng-model="Notify.loggedInEmail[result.email]" />
                                                    <input type="hidden" ng-model="Notify.postId[post.id]" />
                                                    <input type="hidden" ng-model="Notify.destEmail[post.userEmail]" />
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
                                            <button class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="notify()" type="button">
                                                Notify
                                            </button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
```

I tried with ng-init="Notify.destEmail={{post.userEmail}}" but it didnt give me the actual value.

Tried with many options but no joy, I am new to Angular so , could you pls assist

Comment: Is `Notify.destEmail` an object? Can you post at least an example of how the object looks like - that is what properties the object contains. Also, please post an example of the properties that the `allposts` object contains

Comment: Notify is a Java Object and destEmail is one among others variables in that object. allposts is an array of Post Java objects which conatins, postText, userEmail variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the {{ }} in the ng-init, Angular will evaluate that for you without them.

The problem, as I understand your situation to be, is that if you make this work then the properties on the Notify object will always be set to the last element in your posts array, as in each iteration you are setting the Notify object equal to the current item in the loop.

What might make more sense is to set the values on the Notify object when you click the notify button and call the notify() function, changing it to include the post value for the current row.

```
<button class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="notify(post)" type="button">Notify</button>
```

Something like this fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/CMnxW/1/

Comment: Thank you so much Brian! You are the guy, it worked like charm! :) thanks for helping, am totally new to this Angular JS! :)